# Imprimir Elementos desde Listas Diferentes Alternando Índices

Tags: python

Teniendo las siguientes listas les aplico algunas operaciones con Numpy

```
import numpy as np 

punDistribucion = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cajEntAsignado  = [98, 86, 99, 89, 89]
tiemDesAsignado = [11, 14, 11, 12, 12]
cajEntRegistrado  = [100, 86, 97, 93, 94]
tiemDesRegistrado = [10, 10, 15, 15, 12]

asignado = [list(x) for x in zip(cajEntAsignado, tiemDesAsignado)]
registrado = [list(x) for x in zip(cajEntRegistrado, tiemDesRegistrado)]
diferencia = (np.array(asignado) - np.array(registrado))
eficiencia = ((np.array(tiemDesAsignado) - np.array(tiemDesRegistrado)) / np.array(tiemDesAsignado)* 100)
```

Necesito imprimir la información resultante de esta manera:

```
Punto # 1
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 9.1%
Punto # 2
Diferencia de cajas = 0
Diferencia de tiempos = 4
Eficiencia = 28.6%
Punto # 3
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = -4
Eficiencia = -36.4%
Punto # 4
Diferencia de cajas = -4
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -25.0%
Punto # 5
Diferencia de cajas = -5
Diferencia de tiempos = 0
Eficiencia = 0.0%
```

Al generar la impresión directa, se imprime correctamente, y siendo pocos los elementos en las listas, no importa generar un código con 0% de eficiencia como el siguiente:

```
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[0][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[0][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[0],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[1]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[1][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[1][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[1],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[2]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[2][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[2][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[2],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[3]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[3][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[3][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[3],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[4]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[4][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[4][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[4],1)}%")
```

Pero si las listas tienen cientos o miles de elementos la cosa cambia. Necesito generar un código eficiente que me permita imprimir el mismo resultado previendo que las listas tendrán "n" cantidad de elementos.

Lo intente de la siguiente manera y me perdí en algún lugar del problema:

```
for elemento in range(len(punDistribucion)):
    print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[elemento]}")
    for fila in diferencia[0]:
        for columna in fila:
            print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {columna}")
    for fila in diferencia[1]:
        for columna in fila:
            print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {columna}")
    for fila in eficiencia:
        for columna in fila:
            print (f"Eficiencia = {round(columna,1)}%")
```

Logre generar el conteo de los puntos de distribución, pero la información entre el primer punto y el segundo no la he podido generar correctamente:

```
Punto # 1
Punto # 2
Punto # 3
Punto # 4
Punto # 5
```

¿Me podrían ayudar a encontrar algo que me permita imprimir la información como la necesito?, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu mismo tienes la respuesta! Solo fijate en el ejemplo que hicistes puedes sacar el patrón que necesitas, mira como cambian los numeros:

```
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[0][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[0][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[0],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[1]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[1][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[1][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[1],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[2]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[2][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[2][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[2],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[3]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[3][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[3][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[3],1)}%")
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[4]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[4][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[4][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[4],1)}%")
```

Puedes ver como siempre se repite lo mismo a excepcion del contador que aumenta en una unidad en tu código, teniendo esta forma:

```
print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[i]}")
print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[i][0]}")
print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[i][1]}")
print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[i],1)}%")
```

Entonces creo que la manera más sencilla sería:

```
for i in range(len(punDistribucion)):
  print (f"Punto # {punDistribucion[i]}")
  print (f"Diferencia de cajas = {diferencia[i][0]}")
  print (f"Diferencia de tiempos = {diferencia[i][1]}")
  print (f"Eficiencia = {round(eficiencia[i],1)}%")
```

Suerte programando!

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta y me estaba rompiendo el coco... Muchas gracias, me funciono correctamente.